# Interacting with 5 models in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, models

I have a form that needs to be able to interact with 5 (and possibly more) models. It is the following:

Patient - Needs to create the patient record and details (Name, address, etc.).
Form - Keeps track of form name and version.
Questions - Keeps track of questions attached to each form.
Answers - The answers to the questions that the patient gives.
Form Response - Keeps track of the patient that filled out the form, and what form it was.

I've created a layout of the models and what I'm thinking the data would look like:
[Google Doc - DB Layout](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ajwkax6-RzmKdDFieHI4VHVHT3lfWTViZkNxVXNtZkE&usp=drive_web#gid=0)

On the Form Response, the completed_by poly relationship is taking into account that a user, third party, or patient can fill out a form

I am stuck on the best way to go about doing all of this through one form. Right now I am going through the patient controller and patient/new view because I picture this all being related to a patient. I'm just not exactly sure how to do all of this nesting inside the form itself (form_for, form_tag, fields_or?) and then dealing with that in the create action of the controller. Even after going over a bunch of railscasts etc, I'm still very stuck. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on the relations between each of the models?

Comment: @jason328 Sorry about the vagueness. I added a doc to show the structure that I am thinking of. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is what I can understand from the question. There will be five models

Patient, Form, Question, Answer, Formresponse

Now a Form will have many Questions. A Question will have many Answers. A Formresponse will have many Answers.

The model structure should be

```
 class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :formresponses
 end

 class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :formresponses
 end

 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  has_many :answers
 end

 class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
 end

 class Formresponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  belongs_to :patient
 end
```

Now you will have one form for creating/editing patient information, which should be straightforward as no nesting is there.

The creation of Forms will be tricky. Storing attributes of the class Form will be straightforward. To store attributes of the class Question, you would need to handle them in the controller. create form elements such that the name is binded to "questions"

eg,

```
 <input type="text" name="questions[0][name]" value="some name" />
 <input type="text" name="questions[0][help_text]" value="some help text" />
```

note - name and help_text are attributes of your model Question

Now in the controller you can iterate through each value of params[:questions] to get the induvidual form value.

so, there it will be something like this

```
 params[:questions].each do |question|
   q = Question.new(question)
   @form.questions << q #This will append the question to your @form instance
 end
 ...
 @form.save
```

Similarly you can do this for storing responses. I hope its a bit clear to you now

Comment: Thank you for your help. So in the form I'm seeing there being a form_for @patient, and then would you do a fields_for questions and answers? I'm really confused on how to nest those two things inside the form itself.

Comment: Well, if the answers are just the answers the user will input, then you wont need it in the Form edit. The <input> I have mentioned should be inside the form so that its values go to the form action. All you have to do is read them and store accordingly. I think you are getting confused with your usecase. It will be a good idea to write down all the actions you want, then you can figure out how to store values there

Comment: also, it will be a good idea to see how your form elements look like by right clicking on your browser (chrome) and checking the source. Its more of HTML stuff than rails :)

Comment: I can write a full fledged sample form for you if you want with its controller actions

Comment: That would be really helpful. The more I think about this, the more I wonder if it would be better to separate out patient into it's own form. So the patient would enter their details, then hit "submit" and that would take them to the forms_controller new action where the form, questions, and answers would be handled. I can just see it being a mess when those forms need to be edited. From a UI perspective it might not be as fluid, but form a coding side I can see it being much better this way. What do you think?